# Is there any method to get grammatical words separated in PHP?

Tags: php, function

If I have a field_name which is grammatically correct. And I want to separate it by using space.

For example,

1. field_name is **CylinderConfiguration**, and I want it like **Cylinder Configuration**
2. field_name is **NoofCylinders**, and I want it like **No of Cylinders**

Please note capitalization is not the recognizable character in the strings whole string may be in small.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I want to make a function to do this, which will take the string and output a grammatically correct (space separated string).

Comment: Recognizing English is not computers' strong point.

Comment: Are all the field names Pascal cased?

Comment: no not all field_names are pascal cased.

Comment: This is likely impossible if there is no "recognizable characters", somethings in life we have todo manually unfortunately. :(

Comment: How would the computer know if `often` were one word or two separate words `of`, `ten`?  I think the short answer to your question is no.  The long answer is, even if there were a way, it's not 100% reliable.

Comment: This is NOT the way to go, the examples here are the simple to point out and the humorous ones, there are more complex words and grammar situations which aren't this straightforward. Separate your words by default so you can strip out the separator afterwards or make a translation table for your columns to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by using the dictionary in `/usr/share/dict/words` (or just downloading a word list).

The algorithm in pseudo code would then go like this:

```
counter = 0
make input lowercase
loop i from 0 to length of input:
    if sub string from 0 to i of input is in dictionary:
        grammatical_words[counter] = sub string from 0 to i
        add one to counter

echo all words from grammatical_words
```

The down side with this is that any string starting with a or i will basically fail - a string like `algorithm` would be split into `a` and then have no further matches. That means that you'd need to disallow certain words if you are confident you don't use them. Also, compound words such as `often` or `desktop` would not have the expected behaviour. Words that have a word in their root, e.g. 'tablet', 'mobile', 'popular' etc would also fail.

With some tweaking, this could work though. I would make a custom word list rather than using the system dictionary if you know what words you use to speed things up and to avoid false positives.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any way to do this?

Yes.
Moreover, there is always *more than one way to do it.*
One example out of thousands others is a domain name `expertsexchange` that can be split either as `experts exchange` or `expert sex change`.

Instead of implementing such a sort of AI for such a trivial task like printing field names, I'd suggest to either leave them as is for automated purposes, like PHPmyAdmin does, or create a replacement table hardcoded in your code. It will save you a crapload of time on such a trifle task.

One may suggest you to change your naming convention to underscore-as-a-word-separator way, which can be easily converted to space but I would advise against that. Database table names arent' intended to be used in the user interface.
Don't be lazy, create output field names manually.

Comment: nice example, but my fields don't have such confusion. :)

Comment: @Mohan I read "NoofCylinders" as "Noof cylinders". What do I know, sounds like a brand name. "No of" isn't really "grammatical".

Comment: I guess "No" means "Number" in this case